# Why can I instantiate Deque but not List?

Tags: python-3.x, deque

Given the following code snippet, why am I able to instantatiate Deque but not List? Both are aliases for their respective classes yet the latter raises a `TypeError: Type List cannot be instantiated; use list() instead` while the former works the same as `deque()`.

```py
from typing import Deque, List
from collections import deque


class TopologicalSort:
    def __init__(self, graph):
        self.graph = graph
        self.topological_order = deque()  # OK
        self.topological_order2 = Deque() # OK
        self.topological_order3 = list()  # OK
        self.topological_order4 = List()  # TypeError
```

Comment: Found an answer (somewhat) soon after posting this. In `typing.py`, List is created by aliasing `list` with `inst=False`, making it so that trying to instantiate it throws a `TypeError`. I guess the real question then is why was this choice made?